# How to solve 1 not === 1 in react

Tags: reactjs

`state.item.type: 1,` then in arrow function `if this.state.item.type===1 return video else err.` but it output err

This is for a react gallery I working on, type is define which media the item is

**The state:**

```
state = {
    item: [
      {
        id: 0,
        src: "https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1551706646-9c816bfbff8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80",
        h: "h",
        p: "p",
        divid: "id1",
        type: 1,
      },
   ]
}
```

**The arrow function:**

```
type = (e) => {
    if (this.state.item.type === 1) {
      return 'video';
    } else {
      return 'err';
    }
  }
```

**The output:**

```
<h1>{type}</h1>
```

I expect the output of video in h1, but the actual output is err

Comment: item is an `array`, so you need to write it like this: `this.state.item[0].type`

Comment: `this.state.item` is an `Array`. You should use `this.state.item[0].type`

Comment: I don't understand how you can write this.state.item.type if this.state.item is Array hmm.

Comment: you are not actually invoking the function {type} , also that type is declared inside class so it should be { this.type() }  , plus your state access should be this.state.item[0], since its an array value

Comment: @vlad-grigoryan because it's possible that someone writes react code, without understanding very basics of javascript.

Comment: @dfsq you are absolutely right,  so my suggestion who make like mistakes:  learn javascript at first then maybe you can write code))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `this.state.item.type` to `this.state.item[0].type`.
2. You must write `<h1>{this.type()}</h1>` to call your function immediately.
3. And it's likely to have different names of states and functions.